# "Deeply appreciated" or "dearly appreciated"

Tags: word-choice

I want to express my great satisfaction of this person. Are there any differences between the two sentences?

> This shows a great sense of responsibility which is **deeply**
>   appreciated.
>
> This shows a great sense of responsibility which is **dearly**
>   appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Being a possible collocation of *appreciate*, "deeply appreciated" would be more suitable. *Dearly*, on the other hand, will also intensify the meaning of appreciate by adding a sense of "very much".

Comment: *Dearly appreciated* would be understood, but it's [vanishingly rare](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deeply+appreciated%2Cdearly+appreciated&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) by comparison with the "stock phrase" *deeply appreciated*. The only nuance I see is that using "dearly" shows you don't have much of a feel for standard usage.

Answer (score 1):

There's a *deep* difference between the two.

Something *deeply* appreciated is *profoundly* or *thoroughly* approved.

Something *dearly* appreciated is done so with *fondness* or *affection*, which is not the sentiment you want to convey in this case.